# Why $\frac{\pi}{12}$ equals to $\frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm going back to basic trigo for the sake of being able to help my kids and also being bad younger at it, I want to be able to overcome that lack of understanding and honestly, I hate unfinish business.

So please bear with me if you feel my question  is really basic or stupid (and if you feel I should close it, please leave a comment)

I was going through this [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781848002890) and at the 17th page, it said something like that:

$$\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Looking on the net, it says something about angles in the triangle but the lack of precision is appaling and I could not get it.

Your insights are more than welcomed

Comment: Can you subtract fractions? What is $1/3 -1/4$?

Comment: Well:$$\frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{4\pi}{12} - \frac{3\pi}{12}=\frac{4\pi-3\pi}{12} =\frac{\pi}{12}$$But this may not be what you're looking for?

Comment: $1/3 - 1/4 = (4 - 3)/12$ is the simplest, but not sure if this is the approach you need or whether some property of the geometric object (by the way, the link you give doesn't go to any particular page, just to details of the book itself).

Comment: Would be interesting to understand what mental barrier prevented you from seeing this...

Comment: Hi @YvesDaoust, that's an interesting question: As a French man, one word: school (no capital letter because they deserve only scorn) and also the people who work inside (no, I don't call them teachers, they are not deserving the title)

Comment: @AndyK Since you say you are doing this for your kids, this is a good opportunity for you to see that without *basic* arithmetic skills (multiplication tables, **fractions**, some exponents, etc.) nobody has much chance to understand trigonometry or any other a little more advanced material.

Comment: Hi @Joanpemo, I felt very very bad for not seeing something so simple... But the lesson has been learnt. :) And definitely, I'll even tell them that I missed that. There is no age to learn

Comment: Hi @jim I will put the page's number tonight. I was reading it this morning but I got stucked and I could not get through it.

Comment: @jim `p17`. Just looking at it, why making a big deal about nothing -_-

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{4\pi}{4\cdot3}-\frac{3\pi}{3\cdot4}=\frac{4\pi-3\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi\left(4-3\right)}{12}=\frac{\pi\left(1\right)}{12}=\frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: Hi @jan-eerland, thanks for your answer. it seems to be downright basic and I'm blushing of shame looking at it. Are there no special rules here? I thought there was something more in it ...

Comment: @AndyK If you have been away from mathematics for some years than it may not be obvious. Don't feel bad.

Comment: Hi @MathMajor, thanks for the uplifting comment. I was always bad at geometry. As I said in the comment's answer to Yves's comment, the teachers have some responsibilities about it. But anyway, it is never too late and Jan's answer made me understand something that eluded me.

Comment: @AndyK You're welcome, I'm glad that I good help

Comment: Hi @JanEerland, I was going a bit mentally about my question yesterday and well a bit like the (in)famous [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), I've figured that I wanted to know how our 2 chaps were able to break it that way $\frac{\pi}{3} -\frac{\pi}{4}$ and not like that $\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{2}$? Any hints are more than welcomed ...

Answer (score 12):

**The hard way**:

The Tchebytcheff polynomial of order $12$, such that $T_{12}(\cos(x))=\cos(12x)$, is

$$2048x^{12}-6144x^{10}+6912x^8-3584x^6+840x^4-72x^2+1.$$ We equate it to $-1=\cos(\pi)$ and we set $x^2=t$, giving

$$2048t^{6}-6144t^{5}+6912t^4-3584t^3+840t^2-72t+2=0,$$

which is a perfect square by symmetry, and

$$2(32t^3-48t^2+18t-1)^2=0.$$

We know that $\cos^2(\frac\pi4)=\frac12$ is a root, and by synthetic division we factor

$$2 (2 t-1)^2 (16 t^2-16 t+1)^2=0.$$

Then taking the appropriate root $$\cos^2\left(\frac\pi{12}\right)=\frac{\sqrt3+2}4$$ and $$\cos\left(\frac\pi{12}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{6+2\sqrt6\sqrt2+2}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}4.$$

On another hand,

$$\cos\left(\frac\pi3-\frac\pi4\right)=\frac12\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}4,$$ which seems to substantiate the claim.

Comment: I love the hard way. Thanks for your uplifting answer; You are a Teacher, a real one. Only minor issue is I will have to provide work, Ah well, definitely can do that :)

Comment: +1 fun way! But of course one needs to be careful at the end as $\cos x = \cos y$ "not implies"  $x = y$ (PS do you know how to make a "not imply" symbol?

Comment: @ant: precisely why I said "seems to substantiate".

Comment: This answer illustrates the potential to learn something interesting by clicking on any MSE question, no matter how modest it looks. :-)

Comment: nice way to look at a simple problem. But i must say it is not just hard but rather too hard for the problem at hand. Anyway +1 to add the "fun quotient" on MSE.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the discomfort here stemmed from the use of an abstract symbol. We're using a symbol $\pi$ to represent a number, $3.14159\dots$, which we otherwise cannot possibly write down in its entirety (the digits go on forever!). Remember that $\pi$ is just a number.  It's somewhere between $3$ and $4$, closer to $3$. It acts like any other number during mathematical operations.

If you see something like $$\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4}$$ you can try reading it verbally to clarify what is happening, *"one third of pi minus one fourth of pi"*. If we disregard the $\pi$, then this is just a third of *something* minus a fourth of the same thing. What's a third minus a fourth of something? A twelfth of something.

$$\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{4}{12}-\frac{3}{12} = \frac{1}{12}$$

Then we must have one twelfth of pi.

$$\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4} = \pi\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=\pi\left(\frac{1}{12}\right)=\frac\pi{12}$$

Comment: Hi @zahbaz, I've tried that $$\frac{\pi}{6} - \frac{\pi}{2}$$ to see the result, that is way different. So I've got my answers. Overcoming my fear of formalization. Thank you again